# Apache split wildcard sub-domain for ProxyPass

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

I have Apache config where I would need to split the http host domain which includes dashed subdomain and build a new path using these 3 of these matching groups in proxy pass or rewrite rule.

Example urls:

- **kube-test-selfservice.example.com/app/**
- **kube-staging-selfservice.example.com/app2/**

Would need to proxied to:

- **balancer://kubernetes/test/selfservice/app/**
- **balancer://kubernetes/staging/selfservice/app2/**

[image: desired proxy]

It is important that the **test** and **selfservice** in this example are captured as these values change. **kube** can be hardcoded for distinguishing this host under.

I currently only have basic proxy setup, have tried multiple regex rewrites, but as I am not very familiar with apache, would like some advice on that part.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AddDefaultCharset Off

    <Proxy "balancer://kubernetes">
       BalancerMember http://192.168.1.244:30001 route=node1 timeout=600
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / "balancer://kubernetes/"
    ProxyPassReverse / "balancer://kubernetes/"

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, i try to run below and it worked :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kube-([a-z0-9_]+.)?-([a-z0-9_]+.)?.example.com [NC]  
RewriteRule "^/?(.*)"  http://kubernetes/%1/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Used URL :

> http://kube-test-selfservice.example.com/app/

URL Rewritten  to :

> http://kubernetes/test/selfservice/app/

Comment: Thanks, I actually went with something similar using RewriteCond to create separate matching groups, but used the proxy directive [P] instead.